# Getting a linked library (DLL) into another DLL while compiling

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, reference, compilation

I have a solution in VS12 with two projects. When I compile the solution, I get two DLLs, one from each project. However, I'd like to have just one, single DLL containing both of them.

What would be the easiest way to do that? Ultimately, I need all my chunks, auxiliary classes and such to be automatically shoved into the DLL that I get, simply based on the fact that they're linked to it.

Comment: Can you create a statically linked library in one project and include that in the second?

Comment: @unxnut Not sure. Usually I just reference the DLL using the solution explorer. How does one link a file **statically**?! Thanks.

Comment: In the project, you should change the settings to create a statically linked library (with a `.lib` extension) as the target instead of a `.dll`.  That library can be imported into the other `.dll`.

Comment: @ThomasB. Please read the question. I'm not looking for means to **merge** DLLs. In fact, I can't in this particular case go that way.

Comment: @unxnut Put your comment as a reply, please.

Comment: I do not see an answer box any more.  Guess your question is marked as a duplicate of another that has been answered.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Why not? You get 2 DLLs but you want only one. Merge them in a post build step.

Comment: @unxnut Sorry. Apparently somebody was trigger happy, didn't understand the question and instead of clarification voted it for closing. That's the way SO works. One's got to accept certain cons to get the pros, haha. Anyway - I don't see the option to create a LIB file. I can only produce DLL and EXE...   :(

Comment: I think, @unxnut thought, you are talking about native c/c++ projects, where LIBs and static linking makes totally sense. But for .NET, visual studio always creates different assemblies from different projects in different DLLs.

Comment: @ThomasB. Dang... Too bad. I suspected it but hoped that there was a way around it (other then after-compile merge). Thanks, mate.